# How to compile Vim with GUI?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, xorg, gvim, compile

I want to learn how to compile vim from the sources, because there are some additions that I want to add, and learn how to deal with this situations, but until now I didn't have success doing it, I can compile vim, but without its GUI

I think it's a dependencies problem, but I can't figure out which packages I have to install, what are the dependencies to compile vim with its gui?

I found an article about [how to compile gvim](http://aufather.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/building-gvim/), but I don't have the packages for install in my ubuntu 10.10 repositories, I hope to find some help with this

Greetings

Comment: As far as I can tell the tutorial you are referring to is not relying on packages at all. I mean, all dependant libraries are downloaded in source code form. Also you could be more specific about what part of compilation is giving you an error, or what dependencies are unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the `gnome-devel` package, it should pull in all the dependencies you need.  Then start from `configure` again to recognize the new package.